# Displaying the image in browser directly instead of downloading

Tags: azure-container-service

We want to display the image of jpeg in Azure Blob Storage in browser directly instead of downloading it, like . How can we set the content type of the blob? Is there any setting we can set in Azure Blob Explorer?